# Make Multiple http calls based on previous responses in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have to make multiple http calls for my angular2 application. I first have to make one call, wait for the response, retrieve the next call's url from it and make the subsequent call. Similarly, my third call is based on 2nd call's response. I have to perform this operation until the response of a http call has no url to the next call. The problem here is I have no way of knowing how many calls i am going to make( It is solely dependent on the current response, if it has link to next call). Also I need to consolidate the response from all the calls.

Here is the response of each call.

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": 5,
    "pageSize": 500,
    "totalSize": 3000,
    "entries": [],
    "nextPage": {
      "href": "http://someurl?
       requestParam=someValue&page=1&pageSize=500",
      "rel": null
     }
   }
}
```

I have to extract the value from nextPage attribute and make the http call until i get the the response where nextPage attribute is null like below.

```
{
  "data": {
    "page": 5,
    "pageSize": 500,
    "totalSize": 3000,
    "entries": [],
    "nextPage": null
  }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to make one call. I am not sure how to 
   chain these calls.

```
private load(extraUrlParam?: any) {
    let me = this;
    let url = me.getUrl(type, extraUrlParam, null);

    me.pHttp.get(url, this.getHttpOptions())
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("data received");
             me.data = this.preProcessData(data);
             me.dataSubject.next(this.data);
        },
        error => {
            this.dataSubject.error(error);
            me.handleError(error, url, type);
        });

    }
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the second, third, etc... set the url to the nextPage href?

Comment: You could use recursion, but you don't even need to, and could make all the calls (except the first one) in parallel: since you have the total size (3000) and the page size (500), you know that there should be 6 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion. Here is an example. It will execute sequence and accumulate a result till a condition is met.

```
 function getNext(acc, res) {
   return res < 10 ? 
      Rx.Observable.of({acc: acc + ':' + (res+1), val: res+1})
        .switchMap(({acc, val}) => getNext(acc, val)) : 
      Rx.Observable.of({acc:acc, val: 'done'});
  }

  Rx.Observable.of(0)
    .switchMap(x => getNext(x, x))
    .subscribe(({acc}) => console.log('result:', acc))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried recursion suggested by @ mast3rd3mon and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution. But what comes to mind is something recursive like @mast3rd3mon suggested:

Call loadData() once

```
private url:string;

private loadData(extraUrlParam?: any){
    let me = this;
    this.url = me.getUrl(type, extraUrlParam, null);

    this.load(extraUrlParam);
}
private load(extraUrlParam?: any) {
    let me = this;

    me.pHttp.get(url, this.getHttpOptions())
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("data received");
             me.data = this.preProcessData(data);
             me.dataSubject.next(this.data);

             // CHANGE THE URL HERE
             me.url = RECIEVED_URL;
             me.load(extraUrlParam);
        },
        error => {
            this.dataSubject.error(error);
            me.handleError(error, url, type);
        });

    }
```